# Video player shows black border

Tags: css, html, video

I use a HTML5 video player and it works, but it shows a 1/2 pixel border on the right side.
I already checked if it was because the video itself and I tried to set

```
border:solid 0px black;
```

but that didn't help.

My current code:

```
<video id="video" autoplay>
  <source src="intro.mp4" type="video/mp4" id="video">
  Your browser does not support the HTML5 player.
</video>
```

and the style

```
#video{
    width:80%; right: 0; top: 0;
    display:none;
    border:solid 0px black;
}
```

results in

[image]

If someone could help me out, I would be really happy :D

Thanks

Comment: why not if you share your code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10203437/html5-video-in-ie9-is-showing-a-black-border-on-its-both-sides

Comment: @Mihai I tried that, but it leaves a long border trough my text underneath it. And border:none results the same

Comment: Is it the same on all browsers?

Comment: @Mihai No in IE11 it shows a green screen ( which is due my video card? ) but when I use the effect to resize it it shows black borders on both sides. Chrome ( the picture ) shows just one border on the right.

Answer (score 37):

I found the following to be the best solution for removing the 1px border:

```
video {
    clip-path: inset(1px 1px);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue and this solution works in Chromium browsers but not in Firefox.

Comment: This worked for me on both Chrome and FF. Thanks!

Comment: No probs @SamAssoum

Comment: Thank you @timbari!! Works like a charm. Tested in Chrome, Opera, Firefox and Edge.

Comment: Glad it helped @RichardKühleis - thank you for testing across browsers :)

Answer (score 6):

NONE of this is right. This is a focus thing. You need to do:

```html
video:focus { outline:none; }
```

// or choose a color or transparent or something other if you are needing the focus for ADA/WCAG compliance.

Comment: Check your selector and make sure they match. This is explained elsewhere on here. This is the correct method. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57608693/how-to-remove-the-outline-on-my-video-player

Comment: This should be selected as an answer! Works perfectly, looks like chrome ads some outline to the video element on :focus.

Answer (score 4):

it actually a quite known issue. a fix of hide it a bit solves it ->
Give the parent element, who wraps the video overflow: hidden
and the video (position relative/absolute) left:1px.

Like this:

Html:

```
<div class="video-wrapper"
  <video id="video" autoplay>
    <source src="intro.mp4" type="video/mp4" id="video">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 player.
  </video>
</div
```

Css:

```
.video-wrapper{
    overflow: hidden
}

.video-wrapper #video{
    position: relative; /* could be absolute if needed */
    left: 1px;
}
```

Comment: that works, thanks. You also forget to close a tag : class="video-wrapper" ***-> > <----***

Answer (score 4):

From this (black video borders):

[image]

To This (no black borders):

[image]

By adding:

```
<video width="103%" style="margin-left: -3px">
```

Answer (score 2):

To improve timbari's solution - if using border radius, borders go out of shape. To fix that, lower the inset values

In react it would look like this:

```
clipPath: 'inset(0.01px 0.01px)'
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
border: none !important;
```

If this doesn't work try adding as well:

```
border-right: none !important;
```

If these don't help please show us your site

Comment: It could also be a box shadow too... so try adding: `box-shadow: none !important;`

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue as well and I can't figure out why it's happening. What I did to get around it was something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <video>
    <source>
  </video>
</div>

.container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.container video {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    transform: scale(1.01)
}
```

I don't know if this is the best way of solving it, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

It have worked on my side to avoid black and white borders.

```
margin: -1px;
clip-path: inset(0px);
```