# html5 video element 1px white bottom border on chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-video

For some reason on Chrome, I get a white bottom border at the bottom of my video container element.

```
<video id="cover" src="video.mp4" autoplay="" loop=""></video>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

This is the computed styles for the `video` element.

```
background-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
border-bottom-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
border-bottom-style:none;
border-bottom-width:0px;
border-image-outset:0px;
border-image-repeat:stretch;
border-image-slice:100%;
border-image-source:none;
border-image-width:1;
border-left-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
border-left-style:none;
border-left-width:0px;
border-right-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
border-right-style:none;
border-right-width:0px;
border-top-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
border-top-style:none;
border-top-width:0px;
display:inline-block;
font-family:Times;
font-size:16px;
font-stretch:normal;
font-style:normal;
font-variant-caps:normal;
font-variant-ligatures:normal;
font-variant-numeric:normal;
font-weight:normal;
height:798.547px;
line-height:16px;
margin-bottom:0px;
margin-left:0px;
margin-right:0px;
margin-top:0px;
object-fit:contain;
opacity:1;
padding-bottom:0px;
padding-left:0px;
padding-right:0px;
padding-top:0px;
vertical-align:baseline;
width:1680px;
```

Comment: Have you tried overriding it with `border: none;`?

Comment: @Petar-Krešimir yes, i've edited to show my computed style. How bout not down voting me until you try putting a video in a html5 element using chrome.

Answer (score 3):

this worked for me

```
video {
clip-path: inset(1px 1px);
}
```

Found it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70374846/19459083

Credit to @timbari

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party, but here is a small and simple hack which worked for me:

```css
video {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem turned out to be an outline. Setting it to `none` solved it:

```
video {
   outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The fix, for reasons I cannot explain, is adding a "display: block;" to your .

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was `line-height`. I set it to `0` and this "border bottom" disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, the problem was box-sizing. Just added

```
-webkit-box-sizing: unset;
-moz-box-sizing: unset;
box-sizing: unset;
```

to the parent container and the border disappear.

Answer (score -1):

I accidentaly fixed this by applying a border radius on the video element.

```
video { border-radius:1px; }
```